# How to remember user input in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have user settings in my shell script. How can I ask user for input and remember it? In example i have in code:

```
ALTERNATEMEMORY="false"
```

I need to ask user for input (when running script in 'configure' mode):

```
echo "Use alternate memory?"
select yn in "true" "false"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) [permament save ALTERNATEMEMORY as "true"];;
        No ) [permament save ALTERNATEMEMORY as "false"];;
    esac
done
```

Script should ask user as above, read his input, and depending of choice set `ALTERNATEMEMORY` to corresponding state. Next time when running script (not configuring, just running) it should remember that setting. What should I put in these square brackets? 
If I'm making mistakes when posting question, please forgive me - this is first time when I'm using stackoverflow.

Comment: You could use  a text file to store the user settings but I'm not sure if this is the best method to remember settings.

Comment: maybe using an environment variable (will not persist after closing a terminal and will not be accessible from another bash instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to remember a setting from one run to the next, even after reboots, is to use a configuration file.  For system-wide settings, these configuration files are usually in `/etc` and could be named, for example, `/etc/myprog.conf`.  For user-specific settings, the file is usually in the home directory with a name that starts with `.`, such as `$HOME/.myprog.conf`.  Pick one of those paths and create the configuration file:

```
echo "ALTERNATEMEMORY=false" >path/myprog.conf
```

Now, have the configuration section of your script update that file as desired:

```
echo "Use alternate memory?"
select yn in "true" "false"; do
    case "$yn" in
        true)
           sed -i '/ALTERNATEMEMORY/ s/.*/ALTERNATEMEMORY=true/' path/myprog.conf
           break
           ;;
        false)
           sed -i '/ALTERNATEMEMORY/ s/.*/ALTERNATEMEMORY=false/' path/myprog.conf
           break
           ;;
    esac
done
```

In the above, we used `sed -i` to update the file in-place.  This works on linux.  If you are on a BSD system (OSX), then you will need to add two quotes to that command like `sed -i "" ...`

#### Doing substitutions with an arbitrary string

If we want to set `ALTERNATEMEMORY` to have the value `$sel` where `sel` is a shell variable containing arbitrary characters, then we need to escape them before doing the substitution.  This can be done [as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29626460/3030305) (assuming the shell is bash):

```
escaped_sel=$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<< "$sel")
sed -i "/ALTERNATEMEMORY/ s/.*/ALTERNATEMEMORY=$escaped_sel/" path/myprog.conf
```

Comment: Thank You for that tip on BSD

Comment: And how I can call settings from .conf file into my script?

Comment: @Bielecki The form that we have used for the file is valid as a shell script.  Consequently, you can simply use `source path/myprog.conf`.  This assigns shell variable `ALTERNATEMEMORY` to the value given in the file.

Comment: Okay, I got it. And what if I need to enter my own variable, eg. `TIMEZONE`? I tried to `read sel`, and then `sed -i '/TIMEZONE/ s/.*/TIMEZONE=$sel/' ~/.file.conf` but then, after executing, inside that config I got `TIMEZONE=$sel` :/

Comment: That is because shell variables are not expanded inside single quotes.  As long as `$sel` does not contain any sed-active characters, try: `sed -i "/TIMEZONE/ s/.*/TIMEZONE=$sel/" ~/.file.conf`

Comment: Unfortunately it does. In example in code I have `TIMEZONE='Europe/Warsaw'`. I assume that slash character would have to be backslashed, but I don't want to require users to backslash every single special character inside reconfiguration script.

Comment: OK.  No problem.  Use `sed -i "/TIMEZONE/ s#.*#TIMEZONE=$sel#" ~/.file.conf `.  If that doesn't suffice, you can replace the `#` with any character that you know is not going to be in your `$sel`.  (On the other hand, if there is no such character, let me know.)

Comment: It was fine until now. Today I came across a problem that I need allow user to enter any character into `$sel`. What command do I have to use?

Comment: @Bielecki OK.  I just added to the end of the answer the code needed to handle arbitrary characters.

Answer (score 0):

Have a `mem.conf` file with the below lines

```
UNSET
TRUE
```

First line can be `SET/UNSET` which is to check if user has already configured and second line can be `TRUE/FALSE` which is to check whether to use alternate memory.

Initially the first line should be set to `UNSET`.

Then write the script `configure.sh` like below :

```
is_set=`head -n1 mem.conf`
if [[ $is_set == "SET" ]]
then
{
echo "Your have already configured the settings."
}
else
{
echo "Use Alternate memory?"
options=("TRUE" "FALSE" "QUIT")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "TRUE")
            echo "SET" > mem.conf
            echo "TRUE" >> mem.conf
            echo "Configuration Saved !!"
            break;
            ;;
        "FALSE")
            echo "SET" > mem.conf
            echo "FALSE" >> mem.conf
            echo "Configuration Saved !!"
            break;
            ;;
        "QUIT")
            echo "Seems like you have not made up your mind yet !"
            echo "Please come back later."
            break;
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option"
            ;;
    esac
done
}
fi
echo "Configuration File : "`pwd`"/mem.conf"
```

The advantage here is that you could force edit `mem.conf` to start from scratch.